# Django how to GET value from template table?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to use values in a table that has been populated from a queryset to load their associated objects in a modal.

Here is a snippet of the code that populates the table:

```
{% for rec in accounts %}
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">
    <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" href="#accountModal" class="document-link btn btn-primary" value="{{rec.subscriber_fields.internal_id}}" >
    </td>
    <td>{{rec.accname}}</td>
    <td>{{rec.subscriber_fields.custom_1}}</td>
    <td>{{rec.acc_county}}</td>
    <td>{{rec.acc_state}}</td>
    <td>{{rec.subscriber_fields.custom_2}}</td>
    <td>{{rec.uploaded_on}}</td>
</tr>

{%endfor%}
```

What I'm hoping to achieve is:

1. click on the button and pass `interna_id` to the `views.py`
2. use `internal_id` to get the object it's associated with
3. instantiate the form in the modal with the object's info to edit

How can this be done? It took me a while to realize that I can't GET/POST from a table like I would a form so I'm really stuck. I'm using function based views. TIA

Comment: On button click, you can send a request to view using ajax GET/POST.
In your view, you can initiate whatever you want from the business requirement and respond to front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a form:

```
<td class='text-center'>
<form method='get' action='#accountModal'>
    <input type='submit' name='internal-id' value='{{rec.subscriber_fields.internal_id}}'>
</form>
</td>
```

Instead of the button, and then in views.py -

```
def view(req):
    if req.method == 'GET':
        internal_id = req.GET.get('internal-id')
        instance = model.objects.get(internal_id=internal_id)
```

And then you can pass whatever data you want from instance to the template as context.

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm! Just had to link the modal to the button and perfecto!!! I really appreciate it. @user7485741